# ajax search bar multiple url value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In ajax url parameter i try to use multiple value to search. one value's data from user what they're enter. The other value will detect event.
but after i enter value there's no result.

here's my code(JS):

```
var currentURL = window.location.href;

currentURL = currentURL.split("=");
currentURL = currentURL[1];

console.log('php/Search.php?key=%QUERY' +  currentURL);

$('#search.typeahead').typeahead({
    name: 'typeahead',
    remote: 'php/Search.php?key=%QUERY&map='+parseInt(currentURL[1]),
    limit: 100
});
```

here's my code(PHP):

```
$key = $_GET['key'];
$map = $_POST['map'];

echo $map;

$array = array();
$array2 = array();

list($key2, $map) = split(',_+', $key);

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","test","test");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$db = mysql_select_db("test",$con);

$query = mysql_query("select `indicate_id`,`indicate_name` from `map_node` where `indicate_id` LIKE '%{$key}%' and  map_sn =".$map." ;");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    $array[] = $row['indicate_id'] ."\n\n". $row['indicate_name'];
}

echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: Please try to clarify your question.

Comment: There's no chance that you intended "$map = $_GET['map'];" instead on line 2 of your PHP?